# Thread synchronization question

Tags: multithreading

I am playing around with threads. I have a question and I think its a very basic one:

I have a class:

```
Class Message {
   public WriteMsg(string msg)
   {
      Console.Writeline(msg);
   }
}
```

I create an object of this class

```
Message msg = new Message();
```

Now I create ten threads and pass this message object to the function executed by the ten threads. Each will pass its thread index to the writemsg , which will be written out to stdout. I wrote and tested the application and its writing thread index 1 through  10.

As you can see I have not implemented no kind of synchronization. If the class is doing just the functionality mentioned above, do I  need a lock mechanism when accessing the object  in the threads ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need synchronization among threads if they are working working with shared variables.
In your simple example there is no shared variable. So no synch is needed

Comment: @user384706 I have another follow up question. I was reading up in asp.net thread pool, which specified that you can create 5 or so worker threads and about 1000 I/O threads, But you can create only so many threads mapping to a core. So would asp.net framework implementation be a user thread  to kernel thread mapping ?

Comment: @asp.nerd:I do not know about asp.net.Generally though you are not supposed to start any number of threads, since the more the threads the higher the contest to gain access to CPU so the worse the performance. Except if the threads are blocked for long periods e.g. for I/O.I guess this is the model that you describe in asp.net, i.e. the worker threads should be about as many as the CPU's and not more to have concurrency and for threads assigned to tasks with a lot of blocking you can have any number.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing if it's methods that modify or read from non-atomic objects than yes. For your case it's not necessary.